# store file outside the storage folder

Tags: php, laravel

I am uploading file by rest api in laravel from postman, but when I upload any file, it uploads in storage folder but I want to change the path. here I try something like that in my controller

```
if ($files = $request->file('profile_image')) {
         
                    $file = request()->file('profile_image');
$file->store('assets/uploads', ['disk' => 'my_files']);
 
            //store your file into database
            $document = new UploadImageModel();
            $document->profile_image = $file;
            $document->users_id = $request->users_id;
            $document->save();
              
            return response()->json([
                "success" => true,
                "message" => "File successfully uploaded",
                "file" => $file
            ]);
  
        }
```

config/filesystem

```
 'my_files' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path() . '/myfiles',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure like this

#### filesystems.php

```php
'my_files' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('myfiles'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/myfiles',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

then you can store file by

```php
$file = \Storage::disk('my_files')->put('assets/uploads',request()->profile_image)
```

and get url of that image you can do like

```php
\Storage::disk("my_files")->url($file) // here $file is coming from database
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$path = $request->file('profile_image')->store(
    'assets/uploads/', 'my_files'
);
```